# Difference Between Persist Security Info And Integrated Security?

Tags: sql-server-2005, connection-string

In a SQL Server connection string, what's the difference between `Integrated Security = True/SSPI` and `Persist Security = True`?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Persist Security = true means that the Password used for SQL authentication is not removed from the ConnectionString property of the connection.

When Integrated Security = true is used then the Persist Security is completely irelevant since it only applies to SQL authentication, not to windows/Integrated/SSPI.

Answer (score 12):

"**Integrated Security**" or "Trusted_Connection"

When **false**, User ID and Password are specified in the connection.

When **true**, the current Windows account credentials are used for authentication.

Recognized values are true, false, yes, no, and sspi (strongly recommended), which is equivalent to true.

**Note:** If User ID and Password are specified and Integrated Security is set to true, the User ID and Password will be ignored and Integrated Security will be used.

The **Persist Security** Info property specifies whether the data source can persist sensitive authentication information such as a password.

The **Integrated Security**  propery specifies the type of database authentication. If the property is set to be false, you have to set your userid and password manually and if it is set to be true you can pass the authentication by your current windows account.

More details, pls refer the following link:

http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa214039(SQL.80).aspx

http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159866.aspx