# Connecting with SQL Server authentication

Tags: sql, connection

Connecting through Sql Server's Management Studio works, however, it will not connect through the web.config connection string.

```
<add name="cnString" connectionString="Data Source=(local); Initial Catalog=MyDB; User ID=andrewbb; Password=myPassword;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

It returns:
Login failed for user 'andrewbb'. Reason: Password did not match that for the login provided. [CLIENT: ]

Both the password and user id are lowercase.  Ideas?

Comment: Is it a windows ID or a SQL ID? If its an sql ID You may need to add "Integrated Security=false"

Comment: did you set the password and user name respectively of the MyDB database in the Sql Server's Management Studio?

Comment: are you in a domain? Is your SQL Server set to Windows Authentication mode only? (This can be checked in the Sever-Properties -> Security)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your log-in details need to keep all the time.
Include following in connection string to keep security info.

```
Persist Security = true
```

Refer : [Difference Between Persist Security Info And Integrated Security?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2009976/differance-between-persist-security-info-and-integrated-security)

Comment: Yes, this was the solution.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding **NETWORK SERVICE** account to the database

[How to: Use the Network Service Account to Access Resources in ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647402.aspx)

[Check This](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqldatabaseengine/thread/e313f2fb-6729-4bcf-bae4-01430cd60781/)