# Connection string using Windows Authentication

Tags: .net, sql-server, connection-string, windows-authentication

I am creating a website, but in the database I use windows authentication.

I know that you use this for SQL authentication

```
<connectionStrings> 
    <add name="NorthwindContex" 
       connectionString="data source=localhost;
       initial catalog=northwind;persist security info=True; 
       user id=sa;password=P@ssw0rd" 
       providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" /> 
</connectionStrings>
```

How do I modify this to work with windows authentication?

Comment: Not sure whether you meant a generic windows account to be used across different peoples

Answer (score 284):

Replace the username and password with `Integrated Security=SSPI;`

So the connection string should be

```
<connectionStrings> 
<add name="NorthwindContex" 
   connectionString="data source=localhost;
   initial catalog=northwind;persist security info=True; 
   Integrated Security=SSPI;" 
   providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" /> 
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: i know you can set a specific AD user to app pool (web app). can you do the same for windows app?

Comment: `Persist Security Info` is probably not needed: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2010059/1869660

Comment: @heads5150: Is it possible that there is no connection strings in my project? am i missing something. i have searched through my entire solution to find a connection string as above. i could not find any. The one that i founded was commented in the web release and web config.. i am using vs express 2013 with local db.

Answer (score 48):

For connecting to a sql server database via Windows authentication basically needs which server you want to connect , what is your database name , Integrated Security info and provider name.

Basically this works:

```
<connectionStrings>      
<add name="MyConnectionString"
         connectionString="data source=ServerName;
   Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;Integrated Security=True;"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Setting ***Integrated Security*** field **true** means basically you want to reach database via Windows authentication, if you set this field ***false*** Windows authentication will not work.

It is also working different according which provider you are using.

- **SqlClient** both  **Integrated Security=true;** or **IntegratedSecurity=SSPI;** is working.
- **OleDb**  it is **Integrated Security=SSPI;**
- **Odbc**  it is **Trusted_Connection=yes;**
- **OracleClient**  it is **Integrated Security=yes;**

> Integrated Security=true throws an exception when used with the OleDb provider.

Answer (score 30):

For the correct solution after many hours:

1. Open the configuration file
2. Change the connection string with the following

`<add name="umbracoDbDSN" connectionString="data source=YOUR_SERVER_NAME;database=nrc;Integrated Security=SSPI;persist security info=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />`

3. Change the **YOUR_SERVER_NAME** with your current server name and save
4. Open the IIS  Manager
5. Find the name of the application pool that the website or web application is using
6. Right-click and choose Advanced settings
7. From Advanced settings under **Process Model** change the **Identity** **to Custom account** and add your Server Admin details, please see the attached images:

[image]

Comment: This solution worked for me, but I was wondering how does this change on identity impact the behavior of the application, in terms of security?

Comment: All actions performed by the process will be run with the permissions/privileges of that account. Don't grant more permissions than needed. A dedicated service account would be advisable. Would recommend checking out the DISA IIS and Windows Server STIG as well: https://public.cyber.mil/stigs/downloads/

Comment: Solution works but just would like to add that when you try to set the Custom account, the account that you are trying to add should already be present in the Control panel > User accounts else you will get error (If you try to add an account that's not present in Control panel > User accounts). So first add the account in User accounts and then you will be able to set it in Application identity.

Answer (score 12):

This is shorter and works

```
<connectionStrings>      
<add name="DBConnection"
             connectionString="data source=SERVER\INSTANCE;
       Initial Catalog=MyDB;Integrated Security=SSPI;"
             providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Persist Security Info not needed

Answer (score 9):

If anyone comes looking for asp.net core, we will have to add connection string in appsettings.json

```
 {
"ConnectionStrings": {
   "DefaultConnection": "Server=SQLServer\\Instance;Database=MYDB;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"
  }
}
```

Source: [add windows authentication sql server connection string](https://qawithexperts.com/questions/503/how-to-add-windows-authentication-sql-server-connection-stri)

Comment: TrustServerCertificate=true
as well if you get "A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted.)"

for Windows Login in .NET Core 6