# Is there a Default connection string when using microsoft sql server?

Tags: asp.net, database, connection-string, code-behind

I'm new to asp.net programming and I'm trying to connect to the database using microsoft sql server. Is there any default connection string in accessing your database in mssql server through your aspx code behind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A: There's really no such thing, there's too much variation.

You will have to make your own connection string. If the SQL Server is not located on the same machine where you are developing: http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-native-client-10-0-oledb-provider/

> Provider=SQLNCLI10;Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Uid=myUsername;
>   Pwd=myPassword;

If it is on your machine and you are using windows authentication (that is, if you log on to the server the same way you log on to your computer), see here [Connection string using Windows Authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14270082/connection-string-using-windows-authentication)