# Connectionstring to server isn't working in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, connection-string

So I'm trying to set up a connectionstring in ASP.NET to connect to a SQL Server.
I've got the servername and that's the structure I'm currently using.

```
 <add name="CRMSQL" connectionString="Data Source=servername\Instance;Initial Catalog=crm;User ID='CRM';Password='****';Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

I know that the username and the password are right and for the Servername I use  something like U444324.And as the instance name I use the name which pops up when I execute:
`SELECT @@servername`
What are possible sources of error?

Comment: Isn't working is not a valid issue description. What is the exact error ?

Comment: Have you tried to connect to the DB with Sql Server Management Studio? If so then try to use in `Data Source` exact what you have in the `Server Name` field of the `Connect to Server` window

Comment: @doctor_Nick42 So I connected it in Visual Studio with the SQL Server Object Explorer and it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace **Integrated Security=True** with **Persist Security Info=True**

**Persist Security** = true means that the Password used for SQL authentication is not removed from the ConnectionString property of the connection.

When **Integrated Security** = true is used then the Persist Security is completely irelevant since it only applies to SQL authentication, not to windows/Integrated/SSPI.

Reference : [Differance Between Persist Security Info And Integrated Security](http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/2009976/differance-between-persist-security-info-and-integrated-security)

Answer (score 1):

1. Create an empty text file
2. Change the extension to `.udl`
3. Once created, double click on the created file.
4. You will be presented with a GUI
5. Follow the steps in `Connection` tab and click on `Test Connection`
6. If successfull, click `OK`
7. Then right click on the file and open with note pad
8. Copy the connection string and replace it with your current one.